# Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap. help needed in debugging

Tags: c, debugging, malloc, free

The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *a = (char *)malloc(5);
    printf("say hello\n");
    scanf("%s", a);
    if(!strcmp(a,"hello"))
        printf("\n hello");
    else
        printf("\n say hello");
    free(a);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This program is written using code blocks and is compiled using c and is run in windows 7. 
what could be causing this error (`Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.`)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably your input is more than 4 chars. Remember, you need 1 byte for terminating the *string*. So you can only input 4 chars. Judging by your `strcmp(...)`, you input more than 4 chars.